# Powershell: Count the occurence of every single "1" string in a txt file

Tags: string, windows, powershell, foreach, count

We have a text file of students and their notes and we have to count how many "1" notes all the students have got.
My code shows how many lines contain the "1" note, but when it finds a "1", it jumps to the next line.
Could you help me please?

for example:

```
Huckleberry Finn 2 1 4 1 1
Tom Sawyer 3 2 1 4 1
```

It should be 5, but it gets 2.

```
$ones = 0

$file= Get-Content notes.txt

foreach ($i in $file) {
    if ($i.Split(' ') -eq 1){
        $ones ++
    }
}

$ones
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the `1` tokens are whitespace-separated in your input file, as the sample content suggests, try:

```
# With your sample file content, $ones will receive the number 5.
$ones = (-split (Get-Content -Raw notes.txt) -eq '1').Count
```

The above uses the unary form of [`-split`, the string splitting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) and the `-Raw` switch of the [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) cmdlet, which loads a file into memory as a single, multi-line string.

That is, the command above splits the entire file into white-space separated tokens, and **counts all tokens that equal `'1'`, *across all lines***.

**If, instead, you meant to count the number of `'1'` tokens *per line***, use the following approach:

```
# With your sample file content, $ones will receive the following *array*:
#    3, 2
$ones = Get-Content notes.txt | ForEach-Object { ((-split $_) -eq '1').Count }
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `if ($i.Split(' ') -eq 1)`

While `$i.Split(' ')` does return *all* (single-)space-separated tokens contained in a single input line stored in `$i`, using that expression in a *conditional* expression of an `if` statement only results in *one* invocation of the associated `{ ... }` block and therefore increments `$ones` only by a value of `1`, *not* the number of `1` tokens in the line at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Thank you mklement0!

I don't understand why, but it works so:

```
$ones = 0

$file= Get-Content notes.txt

foreach ($i in $file) {
    $ones=(-split ($i) -eq '1').Count
    }
}

$ones
```

Comment: I now understand what you were trying to do: count the number of `1` tokens _per line_. This wasn't clear from your question, which I interpreted to mean that you want to count the `1`s _in the entire file_. The way your answer is written means that `$ones` only contains the _last_ line's count after the loop, which is probably not the intent. I've updated my answer to show a way to collect all per-line counts in an _array_, using a single pipeline.